# CentOS 6.7: cannot disable netfilter for Xen bridge

Tags: networking, bridge, xen

Following sysctl.conf settings at Xen host does not work:

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
```

`# sysctl -p`

```
...
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables" is an unknown key
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables" is an unknown key
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables" is an unknown key
```

But bridge module is loaded:

```
# lsmod | grep bridge
bridge                 86778  0
stp                     1613  1 bridge
llc                     3721  2 bridge,stp
ipv6                  342149  50 bridge,nf_reject_ipv6,nf_conntrack_ipv6,nf_defrag_ipv6,[permanent]
```

What am I missing?

Kernel 3.18.20-2.el6xen.x86_64

Comment: Hmm. `sudo sysctl -a | grep net.bridge` shows them on a stock RHEL 6.7 system. Perhaps related to the custom kernel?

Comment: None for me... it's official kernel, installed from centos's repositories, I swear! :)

Answer (score 0):

Falling back to 3.14.42-1.el6xen.x86_64 solved problem...

```
# sysctl -a | grep net.bridge
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
```